# How to style the cell edit component in material table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

So the thing is that I am trying to create an editable table using material-table library and when I click on a cell to edit its content, an edit component shows up on the cell and I want to style the component according to the table style but don't know where to write the CSS for the same.

[image]

here is my code snippet:

```
<MaterialTable 
                columns={columns} 
                data={rows} 
                icons={tableIcons}
                cellEditable={{
                    cellStyle:{
                      //tried applying styles here but didn't work...
                    }
                }}
                options={{
                    search:false,
                    padding:"dense",
                    paging:false,
                    addRowPosition:"first",
                    actionsColumnIndex:-1,
                    sorting:false,
                    exportButton:false,
                    rowStyle:{
                        fontSize:"10px",
                        padding:0,
                        textAlign:"center"
                    }  
                }}
                />
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, most UI component libraries offer some way to render your custom component and so does MaterialTable.

It is described a bit vaguely here: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding

For your case there is an example here:
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable
Click on the custom edit component example and see the code:

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    {
      title: 'Name', field: 'name',
      editComponent: props => (
        <input
          type="text"
          value={props.value}
          onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
        />
      )
    },
....
```